# php conver text into json variable

Tags: php, json, text

I have textarea field where users can write random text. After posting it i need to put this text into json variable via php.

Something like that, text:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply "dummy text" of the printing\typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
```

And this text must be converted into valid json variable. Any help?)

Comment: Give an expample of your expected result.

Comment: {"textarea":"Lorem Ipsum is simply...."} all problems is that this string must be json valid - without double quotes, new lines and anything else non-valid elements

Comment: So you want to remove all special chars?

Comment: not remove - convert them in valid json. After that i must read this json and use it like text in html

Comment: you will need to put escape character '\' before every instance of special char in text. You may use preg_replace to do that.

Comment: can u tell me all every instance of special char?) or if exist any universal function that can do this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `textarea` name is `text` and that form is submitted by POST:

```
$data = array( 'textarea' => $_POST['text'] );
$json = json_encode( $data );
```

---

- Read more about [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

I always do it with trial and error starting from the top row of keyboard and taking all characters on number keys with SHIFT Key. Than add any other chars as needed.

You can also use `addslashes($str)`:

```
<?php
$yourText = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply "dummy text" of the printing\typesetting industry.'

jsonText = addslashes($str)
?>
```